# When the server starts, the message is logged out

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a "npm start" and gives this error.

> "concurrently" ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒७▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒譥▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒, ▒ᯮ▒▒塞▒▒ ▒ணࠬ▒▒▒
>   ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ 䠩▒▒▒.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! 05_html@1.0.0 open: `concurrently "livereloadx -s -p 8080"
>   "start http://localhost:8080"`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the 05_html@1.0.0 open script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you
>   mean to install?
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\lFoster\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-10-29T11_23_36_759Z-debug.log
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! 05_html@1.0.0 start: `npm run open`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the 05_html@1.0.0 start script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you
>   mean to install?
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\lFoster\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-10-29T11_23_36_803Z-debug.log

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "05_html",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run open",
    "open": "concurrently \"livereloadx -s -p 8080\" \"start http://localhost:8080\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "livereloadx": "^0.3.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before?

Comment: $ npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\lFoster\pac              kage.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\lFoster\packag              e.json'

Comment: You mean without packed.json run?

Comment: Your error shows that you don't have `node_modules` which come after running `npm install`. After successful run of `npm install`, run `npm start`.